# heading on every page for each person

Tags: text-processing, awk

My `file.txt`:

```
Adam , 111
Adam ,222
Adam ,333
Tom ,111
Tom , 222
Tom, 333
Dick, 111
Dick, 222
Dick ,333
```

Expected Output is:

```
My list
-----------------------
    List for Adam
-----------------------
    Adam 111
    Adam 222
    Adam 333
    End of list for Adam
.    My list
.   -------------------
    List for Tom
.   ------------------
    Tom 111
    Tom 222
    Tom 333
    End of list for Tom
.    My list
    ----------------------
    List. For Dick
.   ----------------------
    Dick 111
    Dick 222
    Dick 333
    End of list for Dick
```

I was looking to spilt my file by persons name in specific column and add header footer by usuing:

```
awk 'BEGIN {pttern } {action} END{pater}' myfile.txt
```

Thanks for answer and sorry for edition

Answer (score 3):

**`Awk`** approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ head = "List for"; tail = "End for list for" }
     !a[$1]++ {
         if (NR > 1) print tail, name ORS;
         print head, $1;
         name = $1
     }
     END{ print tail, name }1' file
```

The output:

```
List for Adam
Adam 111
Adam 222
Adam 333
End for list for Adam

List for Tom
Tom 111
Tom 222
Tom 333
End for list for Tom

List for Dick
Dick 111
Dick 222
Dick 333
End for list for Dick
```

Comment: `!a[$1]++` is a nice way to do that.